# Objects can be seen after turning off all lights : How to turn off ambient light in Blender/Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I am unable to find the lighting option that would turn off the ambient lighting after turing off all lightings in the scene while using Blender Cycles.
What I mean is, if I turn off all the lights in a scene, the scene is still not completely dark - there seem to be still some ambient light.

Is there any way to turn this ambient light off so that it does not affect my lighting setup?

*PS: I have noticed that if I use a HDR background for lighting and then disconnent the node from the world output - the scene becomes completely dark.*

[image: ambeint light after turning all lights off]

Comment: Play with the settings in the world tab.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Cycles, the Background is *emitting* light. This will affect all objects, which receive light.
[image]

In order for the ojects to not receive additional light, do one of the following.

- Set the background color to black (0, 0, 0).
- [or] Set the strength property of the Background BSDF to 0.0.
- [and] Disable Ambient Occlusion.

[image]

If you don't want your background to appear black, the following node setup restricts the backgrounds visibility to camera rays.
[image]
You can also restrict the visibility of the background with the [cycles settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/objects/object_data.html#cycles-settings). Uncheck everything except **Camera** under *Ray Visibility* and the background emit no light except to the camera.

Comment: This is exactly I have been looking for.I would have come back for the camera settings ! Thank you for posting it even before asking! :)

One more thing, how do you record screen cast GIF like you posted?

Comment: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/964/30849