# Blacks are grey?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm not sure if I can explain this properly, but things that should be black are grey in cycles?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66662/objects-can-be-seen-after-turning-off-all-lights-how-to-turn-off-ambient-light/66684#66684

Comment: Please use the built-in uploader for images: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: I'm guessing your world background color is gray (the default) just make it black.

Answer (score 2):

No. You are seeing grey color in that image is just because the default ambient color in the blender (cycles) is #404040. If you want to change the ambient color to black. Then assign this hex #000000 color value in the World Tab under Properties panel.
Hope this clarifies your doubt.